# Escaping square braces

Tags: beamer, lists, brackets, delimiters, optional-arguments

I want to use some text as the optional parameter to some command. The text includes square braces (`[` and `]`), but since the optional parameter goes within square brackets, unexpected things happen.

**More  info:** I want an itemized list whose bullets are citations like [GMR85]. I used this command:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[[GMR85]] ...
\end{itemize}
```

but it takes the first `]` as the end of optional parameter.

Any way to escape `]`  ?

**Edit:** I specially want this to work in `beamer`. My current result is like:

[image]

Note how `]` is not included the label.

### EDIT 2

This *bug* has been solved in the latest versions of `beamer`.

Comment: Use `{description}` rather than `{itemize}` with lexicon-like lists.

Comment: Also, why don't you use the `bibliography` environment?

Comment: @Caramdir: I always use the `bibliography` environment, but let's just say that there are technical reasons I don't want to do that now. (It's a long story!). As a short answer, you can just assume that I want an enumerate listing whose labels include brackets. (while they aren't citations.)

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, but even `{description}` environment does not work in the `beamer`. (Screenshot: http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/1151044untitled.PNG)

Comment: I found a way to solve your beamer problem, please see my solution below...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem has been fixed in a newer version of beamer.

Comment: In the general case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument covers it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

group the citation...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[{[GMR85]}] ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The Beamer package makes things a little bit more difficult.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\def\braces#1{[#1]}

\begin{frame}{frame title}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\braces{GMR95}] ...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Matten, but it does not work either (I tried)

Comment: It does not work? I'll put a complete example in my answer, I have compiled it and it works fine for me...

Comment: itemize will cause the bullet cross beyond the left margin. See my answer (not really answer actually, just a comparison) :-)

Comment: @Matten: Sorry, I should have described more. I'm using it in a `beamer` slide, and it does not work in that case (but works fine when you use the `article` documentclass). Can you test it in the `beamer` too? (screenshot of my result: http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/1151044untitled.PNG).

Comment: hey Sadeq.. I supplied another approach for your beamer problem. Please see my second code example!

Comment: @Matten: Thanks a lot, it works. It will be nice if somebody can describe what's wrong with Beamer.

Comment: You can submit an issue on the current development project on beamer with your bug. http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/wiki/Home

Comment: @Matten: Thanks. I filed the bug here: http://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/102/.

Comment: Using grouping with {}'s worked for to solve a similar problem with including square brackets for the description of a beamer definition environment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Charles Stewart's comment and Matten's answers, I make the following comparion. I suggest to follow the Stewart's suggestion. If we insist on using itemize environment instead of description, the bullet item will expands to the left crossing the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe=true,margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SX@codeInput}{xleftmargin=0pt,xrightmargin=0pt}{}
  {\typeout{***Successfully patched \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
  {\typeout{***ERROR! Failed to patch \protect\SX@codeInput***}}
\makeatother
\lstset{%
  literate={ï}{}0
         {»}{}0
         {¿}{}0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,    
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\sffamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\itshape,                                 
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,                          
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{Yellow!30},
    frame=single,
    framerule=0.4pt,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    framesep=3pt,
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,
    tabsize=2,%
    explpreset={pos=b}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{description}
  \item{[GMR85]} I am happy.
  \item{[GMR86]} Are you happy?
\end{description}
\end{LTXexample}


\begin{LTXexample}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[{[GMR85]}] I am happy.
  \item[{[GMR86]}] Are you happy?
\end{itemize}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `paralist` also fixes the margin behavior.