# How do I insert a command using braces into the caption of a ctable?

Tags: braces, ctable

I need to place a hyperref command into the caption of a ctable, but this does not produce correct output. For example:

```
\ctable[caption={Properties of the \hyperref[sec:Towers]{Towers} dataset.}, label=table:TowersData, doinside=\footnotesize]{lll}{}{%
1&2&3\\
}
```

produces a table with caption "Towers" and on the next line "dataset.]Properties of the Towers dataset." I assume the problem is with the braces in the hyperref statement, but I need them for it to work properly. Is there another way to include a hyperref in the caption while still using ctable? Perhaps a way to prevent the nested braces from being seen by ctable?

Comment: the problem is that the closing bracket `]` for the optional `\hyperref` argument is terminating the `\ctable` bracketed argument.  put braces around the entire `\hyperref` string to avoid the problem.  there's some commentary on this in the question [(right bracket) inside an optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/579).  (aha! another place where a literal right bracket will get one in trouble!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an extra pair of braces around `\hyperref` to "hide" from TeX the inner square braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\ctable[caption={Properties of the {\hyperref[sec:Towers]{Towers}} dataset.}, label=table:TowersData, doinside=\footnotesize]{lll}{}{%
123456 & 123456 & 123456\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. I guess when in doubt add more braces!