# Using math expression in short caption for listoffigures

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\[
    \{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}
\]


\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    something here
    \caption[math $x+y$ ]{math $\{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}$ }
    % \caption[math $\{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}$ ]{math $\{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}$}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I want to use a short caption for `\listoffigures`. However, the simple math expressions  (`$x+y$`) can work. But a more complicated math expression like

```
\caption[math $\{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}$ ]{math $\{[\phi(t+h),p(t+h)]_2\}$}
```

[image]

does not work.

Am I misunderstanding something in typing math using latex?

Comment: use `{$math$}` LaTeX can't know here that the closing bracket in your formulae is *not* closing the optional argument.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! Straight to the point! Still I am a bit confused why the "simple" case work, but the "complicated"one.

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: useful information here: [`]` inside an optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/579)