# Why do I get an "extra }" error when using a default argument in a theorem name?

Tags: macros, errors, environments, theorems, grouping

Consider the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\Zn}[1][n]{\mathbb{Z}_{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\Zn[p]$

\begin{thm}[$\Zn$]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

This compiles without errors obtaining:

[image: Image showing "Z_p <newline> Theorem 1 (Z_n)"]

Now, if I change the `\Zn` to `\Zn[p]` inside the theorem title:

```
\begin{thm}[$\Zn[p]$]
\end{thm}
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
! Argument of \\Zn has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 \begin{thm}[$\Zn[p]
                        $]
Runaway argument?
p)
! Paragraph ended before \\Zn was complete.
```

Yet the `\Zn[p]` outside the title works fine. Moreover if I put the command in a group, as in `{\Zn[p]}`, it compiles successfully with the expected output:

```
\begin{thm}[${\Zn[p]}$]
\end{thm}
```

Is there something wrong with my definition of `\Zn`? Or is there a bug in how the theorem environment handles its title? Why does this happen?

Comment: Optional argument inside an optional argument: it's a “quite frequently asked question”; the solution is indeed to brace the inner one.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument