# Getting square brackets inside bibtex year field

Tags: bibtex, brackets

I'm trying to get square brackets to appear inside the year field in bibtex, but they disappear in the output. Here's what I've tried:

```
year = {2000 [1939]}
year = {2000 \[1939\]}  
year = {2000 {[}1939{]}}
```

The expected output is:

- Smith (2000 [1939])

But instead I get:

- Smith (2000 1939)

I'm using the Association for Computational Linguistics (ACL) style (\bibliographystyle{acl}), which clashes with natbib. A copy can be found here for example:

https://github.com/jonsafari/acl.bst/blob/master/acl.bst

I'm not sure how to provide a MWE - I could paste the whole acl.bst here, but it's 1300 lines... Sorry, new to tex exchange!

Here is an entire package with a sample document to reproduce this in:

http://coling2018.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/coling2018.zip

An entry like this produces the problem:

```
@Book{Smith2000,
  title                    = {Some Book},
  author                   = {W. E. Smith},
  publisher                = {Clarendon Press},
  year                     = {2000 [1939]},
  address                  = {Oxford}
}
```

Comment: No escaping (i.e. just `year = {2000 [1939]}` appears to be necessary in either `natbib` nor BibLaTeX. Could you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. (Some styles are programmed to show only the first four or last four characters in the `year` field and/or to remove non-numeric characters.)

Comment: I see, sorry, I'm using the ACL style (`\bibliographystyle{acl}`), which clashes with natbib sadly. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Mico I just checked and I can add other characters, so it's not truncating to last four or only numeric.

Comment: The `acl` bibliography style appears to require a package file called `acm2015.sty` (or, maybe, `acm2016.sty`). Is that file available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico I actually got the entire packet from here: http://coling2018.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/coling2018.zip I think coling2018.sty fulfills the same role here. Let me add an example entry to the question to make this easier to reproduce.

Comment: I've taken a close look at both `acl.bst` and `coling2018.sty`. I must confess to not being able to understand how (let alone why) the bibliography style removes *all* non-alphanumeric characters from the `year` field -- for the citation call-outs. (The year labels in the formatted entries are ok.) Sorry. Any chance you can use a different, less dictatorial, bibliography style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{coling2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Smith2000,
  title      = {Some Book},
  author     = {W. E. Smith},
  publisher  = {Clarendon Press}, 
  year       = {2000 [1939]},
  address    = {Oxford}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2000}
\bibliographystyle{acl}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which produces the `.bbl` entry

```
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Smith}2000 1939]{Smith2000}
W.~E. Smith.
\newblock 2000 [1939].
\newblock {\em Some Book}.
\newblock Clarendon Press, Oxford.
```

and the output

[image: The citation reads: "(Smith, 2000 1939)", the bibliography has "W. E. Smith. 2000 [1939]. ..."]

The culprit is ll. 1100-1103 of `acl.bst`

```
  "\protect\citename{" swap$ * "}" *
  year field.or.null purify$ *
  'label :=
  year field.or.null purify$ *
```

In particular the behaviour you see is caused by `purify$`. That function (page 7 of [Designing BibTeX Styles](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf))

> removes nonalphanumeric characters except for white-space characters and hyphens and ties (these all get converted to a space) [and] removes certain alphabetic characters contained in the control sequences associated with a “special character”

So because your year field gets `purify$`'d it loses its brackets. That means we need to stop `acl.bst` purifying your `year`. That is, however, not enough because with the raw year you would end up with

```
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Smith}2000 [1939]]{Smith2000}
W.~E. Smith.
\newblock 2000 [1939].
\newblock {\em Some Book}.
\newblock Clarendon Press, Oxford.
```

in the `.bbl`, that will lead to errors because we can't have unprotected square brackets in the optional argument, see [] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864). So we need to brace the entire year field to be sure.

You will have to modify the `.bst` style to get the output you want. For paper submissions that might not be the best idea, because you probably can't send your modified `.bst` file, but it will work if the `.bbl` is sent along or just pasted into the document.

1. Copy `acl.bst` to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine.
2. Rename the file to `acl-rawyear.bst`
3. Open the file and find the function `FUNCTION {calc.label}`, replace its second block (ll. 1100-1103)

   ```
     "\protect\citename{" swap$ * "}" *
     year field.or.null purify$ *
     'label :=
     year field.or.null purify$ *
   ```

   with

   ```
     "\protect\citename{" swap$ * "}" *
     "{" * year field.or.null * "}" *
     'label :=
     label *
   ```
4. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
5. Use `\bibliographystyle{acl-rawyear}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{acl}` in your document.

Now

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Smith2000,
  title      = {Some Book},
  author     = {W. E. Smith},
  publisher  = {Clarendon Press}, 
  address    = {Oxford},
  year       = {2000 [1939]},
}
@Book{elk:bronto,
  title      = {Bronto},
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  publisher  = {Clarendon Press}, 
  address    = {Oxford},
  year       = {1972},
}
@Book{elk:trice,
  title      = {Triceratops},
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  publisher  = {Clarendon Press}, 
  address    = {Oxford},
  year       = {1972},
}
@Book{elk:ptero,
  title      = {Pterodactylus},
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  publisher  = {Clarendon Press}, 
  address    = {Oxford},
  year       = {1973},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{coling2018}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2000,elk:bronto,elk:trice,elk:ptero}
\bibliographystyle{acl-rawyear}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I really appreciate the thorough response! I'll mention this to the organizers (I really wish that natbib would just work with this...)

Comment: @azeldes `natbib` can't really be blamed here. It is the `.bst` file supplied by the conference that causes the square brackets to disappear. Coming from a `biblatex` background I don't think it is entirely unreasonable of the `.bst` file to do this: Ideally the `year` is only an integer and nothing more. But unlike with `biblatex` where other fields and means are available to display the year of first publication, many `.bst` files don't offer any other way than `year`.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree it's not natbib's fault - I meant I wished this conference's stylesheet would not clash with natbib! I prefer natbib for a bunch of reasons.