# biblatex-sbl special page numbers

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using `biblatex-sbl` and I have this question:

There is a volume that is separated in a comment (in Roman numerals), together with a text edition and a translation (both in Arabic numerals and both starting with "1") - how can I specify my page number? For instance, I want to have this style:

> Vööbus, Arthur: History of asceticism in the Syrian orient. A contribution to the history of culture in the Near East. 3 vols. CSCO 184.197.500, Subsidia 14.17.81, Louvain 1988, 1 [syr. Text]; 4 [transl].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Voobus.1988,
  author     = {Vööbus, Arthur},
  title      = {History of Asceticism in the {Syrian Orient}},
  subtitle   = {A Contribution to the History of Culture in the {Near East}},
  shorttitle = {History of Asceticism},
  volumes    = {3},
  note       = {\citeseries{CSCO} 184.197.500\ifbibliography{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma} Subsidia 14.17.81},
  location   = {Louvain},
  publisher  = {Secrétariat du Corpus SCO},
  date       = {1958/1988},
}
@series{CSCO,
  series      = {Corpus Scriptorum Christianorum Orientalium},
  shortseries = {CSCO},
  options     = {skipbib},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text\footnote{\cite[1 [syr. Text]; 4 [transl]]{Voobus.1988}.}
Filler text\autocite[1 [syr. Text]; 4 [transl]]{Voobus.1988}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are we only talking about the fact that the code as posted does not work (due to the many square brackets) or are you asking about something deeper here?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you rightly, you just need to wrap your square brackets in braces:

```
Filler text\footnote{\cite[1 {[syr.~Text]}; 4 {[transl]}]{Voobus.1988}.}
Filler text\autocite[1 {[syr.~Text]}; 4 {[transl]}]{Voobus.1988}.
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864