# Problem with IfStrEqCase?

Tags: xstring

I am using `\IfStrEqCase` to choose between various options within an environment. In the MWE below, if the line with the actions to be performed for any non-recognised option (`\ifqsbreak{}.....\fi`) is commented out, everything works fine. If I include the line, I get an error message (*Missing number, treated as zero*). I have tried replacing `\IfStrEqCase` with a simple `\if` statement, and it works as I would expect it to.

```
    \documentclass[a4, 11pt]{article}
    \newcommand{\Docform}{TQ} 
    \newcounter{question}
    \newcounter{subquestion}
    \newif\ifqsbreak
    \usepackage{xstring}

    \newenvironment{SubQuestion}[1][nobreak]% The optional argument determines whether the question should be kept as a block
    {%
      \refstepcounter{subquestion}
      \IfStrEqCase{\Docform}
      {
        % Question format for TQ
        {TQ}
        {\subsection*{Q\thequestion.\thesubquestion}}%
      }
      % All other options
      [
        \ifqsbreak{}\else\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} !In a minipage \fi
      ]
    }
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    % This is the closing statement for the SubQuestion environment
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    {
      \IfStrEqCase{\Docform}
      {
        {TQ}
        {}
      }
      % Closing statement for all other options
      [
        \ifqsbreak{}\else\end{minipage}\fi
      ]
    }

    %------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}

    Some opening text

    \begin{SubQuestion}
      Some text in the sub-question
    \end{SubQuestion}

    \end{document}
```

I guess that there is some interference between `\IfStrEqCase` and the `\begin{minipage}` because if i remove the `\begin{minipage}` there is no problem. But I don't see why the `\begin{minipage}` should even be invoked, given that the code should skip over everything within the `[...]`.

Comment: You need additional brace group in the optional parameter of `\IfStrEqCase`. This is due to the fact that the content within the optional parmeter has an also makes use of an optional paramter so it needs to be `[{ \ifqsbreak...[]...}]`.

Comment: Thank you - that has solved the problem!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Comment: @BambOo: It would be better to close it as a duplicate as I am sure this has been answered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument)

Comment: @PeterGrill, as you are the one that answered in the comments, I trust your judgement. Should we reopen to recloe ? as duplicate ?

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate. Not sure how anyone can argue that this question does not "fall within in the scope of TeX, LaTeX"????